# Specify the starting cell of a Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Is there a convenient way to specify the starting cell of a Jupyter notebook?

I'm thinking of something along the lines of the [HTML input autofocus Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp).

For example,

```
{
    "cells": [{
        "cell_type": "markdown",
        "metadata": {},
        "source": [
            "# Run your first Bash command"
        ]
    }, {
        "autofocus": true,
        "cell_type": "code",
        "execution_count": null,
        "metadata": {
            "collapsed": false
        },
        "outputs": [],
        "source": [
            "echo \"Hello World\""
        ]
    }]
}
```

The [The Notebook file format](https://nbformat.readthedocs.org/en/latest/format_description.html) doesn't have anything like this but maybe there's another solution out there.

Comment: Is there a situation where the first cell, even if it just contains Markdown, shouldn't be considered the starting cell?

Comment: I'd prefer to have the first cell with focus to be one of the "executable" cells. That way when a user who has never seen a Jupyter notebook before pushed "run cell, select" below, something with a larger visible impact happens and they immediately get that ah ha moment. If the first cell(s) are markdown, pushing "run cell, select" doesn't have nearly as much impact. Users who have never seen a notebook before might not even notice the focus advancing.